# Sqlite - Cannot operate on a closed database

Tags: python, sqlite, connection

I am trying to insert a small set of rows into sqlite using python and getting an error "Cannot operate on a closed database"

This is my code snippet:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

db_file = "/home/sosuser/mediaserver/camera.db"

def create_connection(db_file):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()
    return conn

def create_task(conn, task):
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO camerainfo(id, cameraid, maplat, maplong, name)
              VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) '''
          
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql, task)

def prepare_data(conn):
    for cam in range(len(camID)):
        print(camID[cam])
        task = (cam, camID[cam], '12.972442','77.580643','testCAM')
        create_task(conn, task)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

conn = create_connection(db_file)
prepare_data(conn)
```

Get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dumpCamera1.py", line 92, in <module>
    prepare_data(conn)
  File "dumpCamera1.py", line 86, in prepare_data
    create_task(conn, task)
  File "dumpCamera1.py", line 79, in create_task
    cur = conn.cursor()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

Not sure where is my connection being closed. Might have done something very silly but would appreciate for pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `finally` clause in the `create_connection` function closes the connection before it's returned.

It looks as if you are trying to create a kind of context manager for the connection, but an  sqlite3 [Connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection) is [already a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager), so this is unnecessary.

You can do

```py
with sqlite3.connect(dbfile) as conn:
    print(sqlite3.version)
    prepare_data(conn)
```

The connection will be closed automatically on exiting the context manager.  You can trap errors raised inside the context manager by wrapping it in a `try` / `except` block.